Why does IntelliJ with Cloud Code no longer deploy to App Engine?
Why did IntelliJ with Cloud Code just stop deploying to Google App Engine?  It worked fine until this past week. Nothing changed in my dev environment.  Now when I try to deploy this appears and nothing happens.  The cursor used to spin (highlighted in yellow) and now it just freezes.

Is there a way to get the darn thing to print out what it is doing so I can debug?
I installed an updated IntelliJ and Cloud Code plugin.  No difference.  Our deployment config looks like this.

I can deploy from the command line using:
gcloud app deploy --quiet target\MyProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml

Did google or IntelliJ change something recently?
UPDATE ON SEPT 21.
We were able to deploy to App Engine Standard by clicking this checkbox in IntelliJ.

However, the message on that screen implies it will only work for Java 8.  Java 8 was deprecated.  We moved to Java 11 a year ago.
Take a look at google documentation here.
https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/create-standard
In particular, this adds to my (and my colleagues) confusion.

It also implies Cloud Code works only with Java 8.
I managed to speak with our Google Account Rep, who helped clear things up.  IntelliJ  Community Edition with Cloud Cloud work with App Engine Standard and Java 11 and later.  Deploy to App Engine with maven and gradle deployment is supported.  Ultimate Edition is not needed.
I have not tried the above yet.  So I can't confirm it works.
I personally find the documentation (in IntelliJ, the Cloud Code plugin, and on google webpage) to be confusing.

Please have a look at this document and check all the
prerequisites you have followed.

I'll take a look at that more closely.  However, it contains this statement, "Note: For the App Engine standard environment, only Java applications using Java 8 runtime are supported on Cloud Code", which doesn't make sense.  Google stopped supporting Java 8 runtime in January.   And we've been deploying with Java 11 on App Engine Standard for about a year and it has worked.

Yeah, that is bad documentation.  We moved to IntelliJ from Eclipse because Google no longer supported the Google Cloud Plugin for Eciplise for Java 11+.  We were told to move to IntelliJ with Cloud Code because it supported Java 11+ for App Engine Standard.  It was working for the past year.  Something else is wrong.

Please share the logs of this issue.
